# Get updates from a server in the background using Pull notification - Android

Tags: android, notifications, background-process, android-notifications

I want to implement a feature in an android app, which periodically pulls information from a server even when the app is in the background / not running.

It should invoke a web service and check for updates at least 3-4 times in a day, and if available pull and show them in the notification bar. When the user clicks on the notification it should open up the app screen.

Is that feasible using pull notification technology? Are there any constraints? Can you share some tutorials that will help me implement this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sudo steps hope these helps you to go ahead.

1. Create One Service This service will call server and gets the
   updated if available and generate the Notification.
2. Set Repeat Alarm using AlarmManger When application launches first
   time every 8 hours that is 4 times in a day.
3. Create BroadCastReceiver which will called by alarm manager every 8
   hours.
4. And From BroadcastReceive's onReceive() method start the Service for
   data sync.

I pretend that you know AlarmMAnager,Service and BroadcastReceiver.

The working tutorial is [Here](http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/periodically-update-data-from-server-in.html)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks!
I found one tutorial that does exactly this: http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/periodically-update-data-from-server-in.html
can u pls confirm ?

Comment: SO please get me the link of the tutorial so I can add in answer, So other can use it

Comment: http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/periodically-update-data-from-server-in.html

Comment: pls check the above link, and let me know if my understanding is correct