# How to update recycle list items periodically

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have a app which is listing agents and their information. Agent have 3 states,

0 - Offline
1 - Available 
2 - Busy

I use Volley for fetch data from Remote server. I need to check Agent status periodically and update particular recycle list item if status changed.

I am try to implement a function, which is send separate Volley request to fetch status data check it against current data set and update data set accordingly.

If you have experienced same challenged what is the best approach to implement such a functions.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463751/get-updates-from-a-server-in-the-background-using-pull-notification-android

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I am thinking not to use services, but try to use some threading mechanism which is directly run with UI thread,

Comment: You can use services with an event bus library like otto http://square.github.io/otto/ you only post a event from your service and catch the event in the UI.

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás than you very much for your advice. At this moment I am using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for inter fragment communication. If you dont mind could you please elaborate your answer.